# Angular2 child class of Http throws error

Tags: angular, angular2-http

I am dealing with authentication headers, one solution is to create a child class extends Http from 'angular2/http' and add default auth headers. I am using the same code from [github](https://github.com/springboot-angular2-tutorial/angular2-app/blob/master/src/app/http/Http.ts), but it throws 
`EXCEPTION: TypeError: backend.createConnection is not a function in [null] code here`. But when I change it back to angular2/http, everything works fine. I cannot find any information about this exception message. Thanks for help!

**Updates:**
I am using the same way the sample does.
This is my service:

```
import {Injectable} from 'angular2/core';
// import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {Headers, Response} from 'angular2/http';
import {Http} from '../common/http';
import {Category} from '../model/category';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {
  constructor(private http:Http) {}
  getCategories() {
      return this.http.get('http://www.google.com')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }

  getCategory(id: string) {
      return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/api/category/'+id)
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

This is my /commom/http

```
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {Http as NgHttp,  RequestOptionsArgs, RequestOptions,  Headers, Response, ConnectionBackend} from "angular2/http";

const mergeAuthToken = (options:RequestOptionsArgs) => {
  let newOptions = new RequestOptions({}).merge(options);
  let newHeaders = new Headers(newOptions.headers);
  let access_token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
  newHeaders.set('Authorization', 'bearer '+ access_token);
  newHeaders.set('Accept', 'application/json');
  newHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  newOptions.headers = newHeaders;
  return newOptions;
};

@Injectable()
export class Http extends NgHttp {
    constructor(_backend: ConnectionBackend, _defaultOptions: RequestOptions) {
        super(_backend, _defaultOptions);
    }
  get(url:string, options?:RequestOptionsArgs):Observable<Response> {
      return super.get(url, mergeAuthToken(options));
  }

  post(url:string, body:string, options?:RequestOptionsArgs):Observable<Response> {
    return super.post(url, body, mergeAuthToken(options));
  }...
}
```

This is part of my app.component:

```
import { Http } from '../common/http';
import { SecurityRouterOutlet } from '../router/securityRouter';
import { RouteConfig, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from 'angular2/router';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, ConnectionBackend } from 'angular2/http';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/view/app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/view/app.component.css'],
    directives: [SecurityRouterOutlet, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [
        ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        CategoryService,
        LoginService,
        ConnectionBackend,
        Http
    ]
})
```

If more code detail is needed, please let me know. Thanks!

**Update2** As @Thierry Templier suggested, I change Http to AuthHttp in my common/http file, so as category service and app.component.ts, but this doesn't help.

The full stack of exception:

```
TypeError: backend.createConnection is not a function  angular2.dev.js:23877 
    at httpRequest (http.dev.js:941)
    at AuthHttp.Http.get (http.dev.js:980)
    at AuthHttp.get (http.ts:24)
    at CategoryService.getCategories (category.service.ts:16)
    at DashboardComponent.ngOnInit (dashboard.component.ts:15)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.ChangeDetector_HostDashboardComponent_0.detectChangesInRecordsInternal (viewFactory_HostDashboardComponent:21)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.detectChangesInRecords (angular2.dev.js:9609)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (angular2.dev.js:9592)
    at AbstractChangeDetector._detectChangesContentChildren (angular2.dev.js:9665)
    at AbstractChangeDetector.runDetectChanges (angular2.dev.js:9593)
```

The dashboard.component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from 'angular2/core';
import { Router } from 'angular2/router';
import { Category } from '../model/category';
import { CategoryService } from '../service/category.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-dashboard',
    templateUrl: 'app/view/dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/view/dashboard.component.css']
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    categories: Category[] = [];
    constructor(private _router: Router, private _categoryService: CategoryService) { }
    ngOnInit() {
     this._categoryService.getCategories().subscribe(
          data => { this.categories = data },
          err => console.error(err)
      );
    }
    gotoDetail(category: Category){
        let link = ['CategoryDetail', { id: category.id }];
        this._router.navigate(link);
    }
}
```

I am using the latest version:

```
{
    "name": "angular2quickstart",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "npm run typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "typings" : "typings"
},
  "license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.13",
    "systemjs": "0.19.25",
    "es6-promise": "^3.0.2",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.4",
    "zone.js": "0.6.9"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.0.1",
    "typescript": "^1.7.5",
    "typings": "^0.7.12"
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide the necessary information that allows to reproduce the problem. How do you use the linked code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `useClass` when you define the associated provider but `useFactory` this way:

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
  HTTP_PROVIDERS,
  provide(Http, {
    useFactory: (backend: XHRBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => new CustomHttp(backend, defaultOptions),
    deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
  })
]);
```

This way you will provide the backend to inject.

**Edit**

I find that there is a problem the way you define your class. You should try something like that:

```
export class CustomHttp extends Http {
  (...)
}
```

and register it with the `provide` function as described above.

Comment: I updates my questions. This approach I will try. But actually I am suspecting there is something wrong with my imports, since my code is almost same with the sample.

Comment: I updated my answer. Use something like that rather: `export class CustomHttp extends Http { ...`

Comment: No, this doesn't help. The exception originates from `function httpRequest(backend, request) {
    return backend.createConnection(request).response;
  } `. Do you think I import wrong ConnectionBackend?

Comment: Again I think that the problem is the way you define your custom `Http` class. You don't register it... Here is a working plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/ukcJRuZ7QKlV73jiUDd1?p=preview.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks so much for your demo and patience!